# Integrating Sybase UltraLite Db to my code

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, xcode, sybase

I am new to ios development. I want to create a local Sybase Ultralite db in my system and

want to perform insert , delete,update on my local Ultralite db present in my system. I went

through many samples, but I didn't get any proper information. For integrating SQLite db there

are many step by step approaches which is easy to follow but for Ultralite none. As I am a

beginner I want step by step approach to create a simple local Ultralite db in my system and

modify it through my code . I really need this very badly.I am using Ultralite db because

there are multiple users of my db, and data they are updating will reflect in the server

also. Where as in SQLite I dont think, it provides this kind of sync mechanism. As far as i

have heard it is used as just a local db  Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite (or Core Data) are definitely the most common SQL interface for iOS. But you're right that it doesn't offer any built-in, integrated, sync mechanisms itself.

In terms of Ultralite on iOS, have you seen the [Ultralite iOS tutorial page](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/ulc/ulc-iphone-tutorial.html)? It's not much, but a start.

Comment: I will follow the steps given in your link. But as I am beginner I was looking for a clear step by step approach. I am not sure whether that link provides an easy approach .

Comment: @Raj The tutorial is pretty detailed, step by step, but I think it presumes some iOS familiarity, too, though. If you've never done iOS development before, I'd definitely suggest you gain some familiarity with that first, and only tackle the Ultralite integration once you have command of iOS development (if you don't already).

Comment: I got some basic knowledge on ios development

Comment: @Raj Excellent. Then I think you'll be good. Clearly, it's not as rich as hundreds of iOS and/or Core Data tutorials out there, but it looks pretty detailed.

Comment: @Raj I'd also suggest that you check out the [Ultralite discussions](http://forums.sybase.com/cgi-bin/webnews.cgi?cmd=listitems&sort_on=none&second_sort=date&sort_method=date&sort_reverse=true&group=sybase%2Epublic%2Esqlanywhere%2Eultralite). I bet you'll get more traction if you ask your Ultralite/iOS questions there.

Comment: Okay.Thanks a lot Rob :) It was a nice info, really helpful